# Could not understand line of code using count

Tags: python

I am taking data analyst course from Udacity and I am new to python,
can you explain the highlighted code for me? I understood the code but the highlighted part

[image]

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Note that the last line in a notebook cell automatically has its result printed. That wouldn't happen if you ran the same code in a normal python script (the comparison would still happen, but nothing would be printed to the screen).

Answer (score 1):

says count of "index `quality` of `low_alcohol`" plus count of "index `quality` of `high_alcohol`" are equal to `num_samples` or not.

result is `bool` (`True` or `False`)